# I don't understand which databases are invalid

Tags: django, django-models, view, django-forms

I'm getting the following data:

`{'name_work': 'рациональные числа', 'writing_date': datetime.datetime(2024, 3, 15, 16, 18, 37, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'student_type': \<TypeStudentWork: TypeStudentWork object (2)\>, 'number_of_tasks': '10', 'student': \<User: Dear Student\>, 'example': \<Example: ответы к 1 самостоятельной\>, 'teacher': \<SimpleLazyObject: \<User: Diana Berkina\>\>, 'image_work': \<InMemoryUploadedFile: только\_ответы.jpg (image/jpeg)\>}`

My views is a class that receives this data and sends it to the form:

```py
class CreateStudentWorkView(View):

    def post(self, request, type_work_id):
        try:
            type_work_obj = TypeStudentWork.objects.get(pk=type_work_id)
            students = User.objects.filter(student_class=type_work_obj.school_class)
            print(students)

            for student in students:
                image_file = request.FILES.get("image_work_" + str(student.id))
                if image_file:
                    initial_data = {
                        'name_work': type_work_obj.name_work,
                        'writing_date': type_work_obj.writing_date,
                        'student_type': type_work_obj,
                        'number_of_tasks': '10',
                        'student': student,
                        'example': type_work_obj.example,
                        'teacher': request.user,
                        'image_work': image_file
                    }
                    print("Initial data for student", student.username, ":", initial_data)
                    form = StudentWorkForm(initial=initial_data)
                    print(form.errors)
                    if form.is_valid():
                        form.save()
                    else:
                        print("Errors for student", student.username, ":", form.errors)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        return redirect('moderator')
```

My model is the model of the work I'm trying to keep:

```py
class StudentWork(models.Model):
    name_work = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    writing_date = models.DateTimeField()
    student_type = models.ForeignKey(
        TypeStudentWork,
        related_name='type_works',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    number_of_tasks = models.CharField(max_length=5, default="5")
    student = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='student',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )
    example = models.ForeignKey(
        Example,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )
    image_work = models.ImageField(upload_to='image')
    text_work = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    proven_work = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    assessment = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='teacher',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I've tried extracting id into fields where the type is ForeignKey. But as I understand I need objects, I don't know how to get them correctly.